# Cannot make python boxplot show median data labels and title, and overall no longer works

Tags: python, matplotlib, boxplot

I have been using python to create boxplots for my research. I recently tried to make changes, as when I ran it I was given two plots (one with the titles and one with the data). After making a number of changes, basically copying from [this article](https://sharkcoder.com/data-visualization/seaborn-boxplot) I am getting a syntax error for the third line, and I don't see why that would be.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BvG4.png)

I had the initial code as [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7Ukq.png) and it worked, I just wanted it to include a title and data lebels at the median. Idk what to do as my paper is due at the end of this week so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `%matplotlib notebook` line. The editor you're using has underlined it in red. `%` works in Jupyter notebooks, but you're using something else I think.